# How to use file-based config for Saml2SecurityTokenHandler?

Tags: federated-identity, wif, saml-2.0, ws-federation

Using Saml2SecurityTokenHandler to validate SAML2 bearer token from internal provider or from ACS. Able to programmatically configure the handler to validate just fine, but it doesn't seem to want to pick up configuration from the microsoft.IdentityModel section in my config file. Constructing a SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionManager seems to have no notion of the named configuration section either so I can't seem to use mySaml2SecurityTokenHandler .Configuration - mySecurityTokenHandlerCollectionManager["NAME"].Configuration.

Is there a good sample of setting this up somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use file-based config, it turns out you simply rely on the FederatedAuthentication context, rather than explicitly constructing the Saml2SecurityTokenHandler:

```
        var handlers = FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;
        var token = handlers.ReadToken(xmlReader);
        var collection = handlers.ValidateToken(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known problem.

Have you tried FederatedClientCredentials --> SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionManager property --> SecurityTokenHandlerCollection --> replace the standard  Saml2SecurityTokenHandler with whatever?

Comment: This is an explicit context where a relying app accepts an assertion as POST data and must validate the assertion. Therefore the SecurityTokenHandlerCollection is not instantiated. However, I am thinking I may pull in the dependencies and instantiate it regardless, and see if I can pull that context in explicitly.